# Cannot execute downloaded file from script

Tags: java, macos-catalina, quarantine

I downloaded a jdk7 tarball to test parity with some old software during an upgrade. When I unpacked it I of course got a bunch of quarantined files. After not finding a way to remove the quarantine flag from the symlinks in the unpacked directory, I finally got smart, unquarantined the package itself, deleted everything and re-extracted the tarball.

```
NS2-MacBook-Pro:tools gus$ sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Users/gus/tools/zulu7.40.0.15-ca-jdk7.0.272-macosx_x64.tar.gz
NS2-MacBook-Pro:tools gus$ rm -rf zulu7.40.0.15-ca-jdk7.0.272-macosx_x64
NS2-MacBook-Pro:tools gus$ tar xzvf zulu7.40.0.15-ca-jdk7.0.272-macosx_x64.tar.gz 
NS2-MacBook-Pro:tools gus$ ls -al@ ~/tools/zulu7.40.0.15-ca-jdk7.0.272-macosx_x64/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  19 gus  staff   608 Jul  7 11:27 .
drwxr-xr-x  43 gus  staff  1376 Oct 14 20:03 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    43 Jul  9 22:27 ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/ASSEMBLY_EXCEPTION
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    49 Jul  9 22:27 CLASSPATH_EXCEPTION_NOTE -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/CLASSPATH_EXCEPTION_NOTE
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    35 Jul  9 22:27 DISCLAIMER -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/DISCLAIMER
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    32 Jul  9 22:27 LICENSE -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/LICENSE
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    43 Jul  9 22:27 THIRD_PARTY_README -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/THIRD_PARTY_README
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    37 Jul  9 22:27 Welcome.html -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/Welcome.html
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    28 Jul  9 22:27 bin -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    29 Jul  9 22:27 demo -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/demo
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    32 Jul  9 22:27 include -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/include
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    28 Jul  9 22:27 jre -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    28 Jul  9 22:27 lib -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/lib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    28 Jul  9 22:27 man -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/man
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    35 Jul  9 22:27 readme.txt -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/readme.txt
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    32 Jul  9 22:27 release -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/release
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    31 Jul  9 22:27 sample -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/sample
lrwxr-xr-x   1 gus  staff    32 Jul  9 22:27 src.zip -> zulu-7.jdk/Contents/Home/src.zip
drwxr-xr-x   3 gus  staff    96 Jul  7 11:27 zulu-7.jdk

NS2-MacBook-Pro:tools gus$ ls -al@ ~/tools/zulu7.40.0.15-ca-jdk7.0.272-macosx_x64/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x  1 gus  staff  110880 Jul  9 22:27 /Users/gus/tools/zulu7.40.0.15-ca-jdk7.0.272-macosx_x64/bin/java
```

This seemed successful since I was now able to run the java command in the unpacked directory from my terminal command line,

```
NS2-MacBook-Pro:tools gus$ ~/tools/zulu7.40.0.15-ca-jdk7.0.272-macosx_x64/bin/java
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
... etc ...
```

And that works for enclosing in backtics or `$()` too but...  but the ant build (or any bash invocation) still can't seem to run it.

```
NS2-MacBook-Pro:tools gus$ bash ~/tools/zulu7.40.0.15-ca-jdk7.0.272-macosx_x64/bin/java
/Users/gus/tools/zulu7.40.0.15-ca-jdk7.0.272-macosx_x64/bin/java: /Users/gus/tools/zulu7.40.0.15-ca-jdk7.0.272-macosx_x64/bin/java: cannot execute binary file

or

NS2-MacBook-Pro:tools gus$ ant
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute ~/tools/zulu7.40.0.15-ca-jdk7.0.272-macosx_x64/bin/java
```

None of this ever gave me problems before Catalina...

So the question is what should I be tweaking to make the JDK work from any context?

Comment: [Set JAVA_HOME on Windows 7, 8, 10, Mac OS X, Linux | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux)

Comment: @DavidPostill the link you supplied merely says to set the environment variable, which (if you read the question) I clearly have done successfully since ant is naming a specific JDK file inside the intended JDK. This question is about quarantine issues.